# Laravel two routes for one method

Tags: php, laravel

I have these routes in web.php:

```
Route::get('/threads/create','ThreadForumController@create');
Route::get('/threads/{channel}','ThreadForumController@index');
Route::post('/threads','ThreadForumController@store');
Route::get('/threads/{channel}/{thread}','ThreadForumController@show')->name('threads.show');
Route::post('/threads/{channel}/replies','ReplyController@store');
Route::get('/threads','ThreadForumController@index');
```

When I go in browser to /threads I must get all threads, when I go to /threads/php I must get specefic threads, but I always has  $channel  value in my controller:

```
public function index(Channel $channel)
    {
        $threads = $channel->exists() ? $channel->threads()->latest()->get() : ThreadForum::all();

        return view('threads.index', compact('threads'));
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you make a different controller action for the 2 routes? Also move your last route up in your list since the `{channel}` will also catch an empty string and your `/threads` get route will thus never be called

Comment: What do you get if you dd($channel); when you go to /threads? You should probably have the action go to another controller action. $channel probably exists as null.

Comment: I get Channel object (but it is empty, attributes array is empty)

Comment: I moved /threads route to the top but it did not help me

Comment: isset() always returns true

Comment: Can you post the value from the dd(). If isset() returns true then empty() may work, but I'd rather not keep guessing. Your /threads (default of the routes) should be at the bottom of those listed. You could try to check that the variable exists and the count is not zero, if $channel is an array.
if(isset($channel) && count($channel) > 0)

Comment: How can you fix what? I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can merge the two route into one:

```
Route::get('/threads/{channel}','ThreadForumController@index');
Route::get('/threads','ThreadForumController@index');
```

Can be changed into:

```
Route::get('/threads/{channel?}','ThreadForumController@index');
```

Then the `index` method can be written as below:

```
public function index($channel == null) {
    if ($channel) {
        //I always go in this way
        $threads = Channel::findOrFail($channel)->threads()->latest()->get();
    } else {
        $threads = ThreadForum::all();
    }
    return view('threads.index', compact('threads'));
}
```

Thus you can serve both purpose with one route and one method.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, one would be this:

```
 public function index(Channel $channel)
{
    $threads = Thread::latest();

    if(request('channel')) {
        $threads = $channel->threads()->latest();
    }

    $threads = $threads->get();

    return view('threads.index', compact('threads'));
}
```

You do have to set getRouteKeyName if youwant slugs('php') instead of id in the route. For instance in your **Channel** model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}

public function threads()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Thread::class);
}
```